# Some OCAML concerns

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, ocaml

So I have a couple of questions, as a newbie trying to learn O'Caml.

In functions, I often times see a | what does that mean? Also, why are functions some times defined as:
let rec a = function 
Why does it specifically equal to function and then the code?

My main question however is, I was trying to write a function that would count the number of times an element exists in a list, so if I had 1, 5,5,6,9 with the target val as 5, then I'd return 2, if target val was 9, then I'd return 1, since it repeats once.

here is my attempt, please tell me what I'm doing wrong:

```
let rec track (x, l)= let rec helper(x,l, count)
    in counthelper
        match l with [] --> count 
    | (a::as) -> if(x = a) 
                    then helper(as,l, count+1) 
                 else count( as, l, count);;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually `|` means [pattern matching](http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/data_types_and_matching.html).

`let rec` means that function can be recursive (call itself). [Tutorial](http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/basics.html).

This is my solution where some useful symbols are changed to `_` symbols. Let it be an exercise for you:

```
let rec count y xs =
  let rec inner n = function
  | __ -> n
  | ______________ -> inner (n+1) xs
  | ____ -> inner n xs
  in 
  inner 0 xs;;
```

Your implementation has some issues.

1. The most obvious one is that you are using `as` in pattern matching. You can't us keyword in pattern matching this way.
2. You need to reread chapter about function declarations. It seems that you are mixing it with function invocation.
3. You are using not curried functions. You did some in C before, don't you?
4. You are using `if` when using using `when` is nicer. This construction is called `guard`.

Comment: I know that let rec can be recursive, I don't understand what's wrong with my function above

Comment: when you let rec innner n = function, why do you n = function, that bothers me a lot and I don't get it.

Comment: @user3276558, `let f = function |...` is short version of `let f x = match x with | ...`

Comment: how does ocaml know what to apply the cons on, like how does it know it is to be applied on the list?

Comment: The cons (`::`) operator takes element and list of elements this sort. Its semantics is hardcoded in OCaml parser. Btw, why you have removed your code from question? P.S. Your questions become very short and easy. IRC conference `#ocaml` on Freenode IRC server suits them more.

Comment: I am trying to fix my code that's why, I will paste it back. It was wrong :(

Answer (score 1):

The `match` and `function` keywords take a list of patterns to be matched. The `|` symbol is used to separate the different patterns. That's why it shows up so frequently in OCaml code.

The `function` keyword is like an abbreviation for `fun` and `match`. It lets you define a function as a set of patterns to be matched against an argument.

Your code has `let rec helper (x, l, count) in ...`. This isn't a proper `let` expression. You want something like this: `let helper (x, l, count) = def in expr`.

More generally your code might look like this:

```
let track (x, l) =
    let rec helper (x, l, count) =
        ... definition of helper ...
    in
    helper (x, l, 0)
```

As a side comment, you're using tuples for function parameters. It's more idiomatic in OCaml to use currying, i.e., to have separate parameters more like this:

```
let track x l =
    ...
```

This lets you do partial application (specify only some of the parameters), and also is cleaner syntactically.

**Update**

Your latest code doesn't return a value because it has infinite recursion.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my code, as per your suggestions, but I am not getting a return value. Can you take a look, I am very close to writing my first ever Ocaml function. :)

Comment: You have infinite recursion in your code. You need to call yourself recursively with a smaller value. (Hint: tail of the list.)

Comment: thank you, let me think about it more carefully. Please don't give me the answer. I want to learn.